# 2 unknown one equation and condition

Tags: probability, optimization, random-variables, convex-analysis

suppose that we have

$P_2+P_3=1-P_1-Q_3$ where $0\le P_1\le 1$ and $0\le Q_3\le 1$ are known, and $0\le P_2\le 1$ and $0\le P_3\le 1$ and $P_2<P_3$ 
can we finde this probablity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can't obtain **a** specific probability from the given constrains
\begin{cases}
P_2+P_3&=1-P_1-Q_3 \\
0&\le P_2,P_3\le 1 \\
P_2&<P_3
\end{cases}
with $0\le P_1,Q_3\le 1$ fixed.  In fact, it's easy to see that
\begin{cases}
0&\le P_2< \frac{1-P_1-Q_3}{2} \\
P_3&=1-P_1-Q_3-P_2.
\end{cases}

Comment: thank you so much for answer

Comment: @moh11aymen you're welcome